# How to change excel data into list

Tags: python, arrays, excel

How can we change excel data into list?
Eg: if we have imported a excel table in python and here we can read the value of a column as:
A= df["Column name"],
then how can we change the value stored in A as array

Comment: what is your input data? how do you import this data from excel to python?

Comment: I'm assuming you are talking about `pandas` since you called your variable `df`. If so, `A` is a pandas Series and to make it into a numpy array, just use `A.values`. If you want a python list, use `A.tolist()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Jack', 'nick', 'juli'], 'marks':[99, 98, 95, 90]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
listt = df['Name'].tolist()
print(listt)
```

['Tom', 'Jack', 'nick', 'juli']